# Exchanging data between nodejs and Python

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

I am new to node and socket.io.  I have a nodejs server that I am trying to use to both spawn a Python process from, and pass data to and from a web page.  On the Python end I'm trying to use Python's stdin/stdout pipes.

Everything coming from Python to nodejs and on to the server works fine.  However, when I attempt to pass data from nodejs back to Python using stdin.write, node crashes with a "write after end" error.  I am wondering if the socket I'm using to receive from Python is conflicting with that I'm trying to send back.  I am using a timer to send data to the web page every second.

This seems to have something to do with Python expecting an EOF when calling sys.stdin.readlines(), however, when I use stdin.end() from nodejs, that's when I get the error.  Interestingly, if I never call stdin.end, I don't get the error, but I also don't receive anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm afraid I don't know enough about socket.io to see what's going wrong here.  Thank you.

IN NODEJS:
Spawning the Python process:

```
var util = require('util'),
spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
py = spawn('python', ['data_collect.py']);
```

Receiving data from Python:

```
py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    python_output = data.toString();
```

Sending data to Browser:

```
var listener = io.listen(server);
listener.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit( 'dataPacket1', {variable_1: data1});
    socket.emit( 'dataPacket2', {variable_2: data2});
    socket.emit( 'dataPacket3', {variable_3: data3});
}, 1000);
```

Receiving from browser and sending to Python:

```
socket.on('messageFromBrowser', function(data) {
    py.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
    py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data.browser_value+'\n'));
    py.stdin.end();   <--- Error happens here
```

});

IN PYTHON:
Sending to nodejs:

```
output = "dataout"
sys.stdout.write(output)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Receiving from nodejs:

```
lines = []

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line !='':
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
return lines
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to combine node and python I think the best solution is to move to a microservice architecture using Seneca.JS. If I was in you I will create a rest interface to communicate between the a python process and node.js microservice. you can find more information [here](https://www.codementor.io/ivan.jovanovic/introduction-to-nodejs-microservices-senecajs-du1088h3k)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.  It turns out what I'm trying to do doesn't seem to be all that widespread.  In any case, Seneca appears to be a wonderful system that might work, if not for this project, for several others I have.  Out of desperation, I ended up using Python's stdout stream to simply print data to node, then used node's server capability to display the data in a browser.  I was able to return data from the browser to Node, but not send it on to Python (the stdin stream was a lot more finiky, and wouldn't respond without me sending an EOF, which I couldn't get to work).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the py.stdin.end().
And make sure '\n' is outside stringify

```
py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data.browser_value)+'\n');
```